# change Subview of superview through IBAction of Subview ios

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, uiviewcontroller

I tried to find a solution here but was unable to,  basically I have an interactive subview that I need to switch to a new interactive subview from within the subview.  I am able to change subviews easily with an IBAction in the main view, but I have been unsuccessful changing the view from within the subview.  Here's the code... which should make what I am trying to accomplish more clear.

in .h of MainViewController

```
@interface MainViewController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet OneViewController *oneviewController;
    IBOutlet TwoViewController *twoViewController;
}

-(IBAction)goToView;

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet OneViewController *oneviewController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet TwoViewController *twoViewController;

@end
```

in .m

```
@implementation MainViewController

@synthesize oneviewController;
@synthesize twoViewController;

-(IBAction)goToView {   
    [self.view addSubview:twoViewController.view];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.view addSubview:oneviewController.view];  
}
```

Ok this all works great, i am able to load both ViewControllers with xib and all their` buttons work  etc. ..
But when I try...

in .m of OneViewController

```
#import "MainViewController"

...
[MainViewController.view addSubview:twoViewController.view];  ...
```

this does not work,  I have tried a variety of things, by adding the twoViewController to the .h of oneViewController, but it crashed...   I am still very new to all this so It is likely I am missing the obvious.  Thanks for help!!

I also tried this in the .m of OneViewController

but it still crashed... although the build succeeded

`MainViewController* mySuperView = (MainViewController*)self.view.superview;
        TwoViewController *twoViewController;
        [mySuperView.view addSubview:twoViewController.view];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This action is being done in the wrong place. If you are trying to add a subview to your MainViewController, you should really handle that inside of MainViewController.m. You are calling:

[MainViewController.view addSubview:twoViewController.view];

but MainViewController.view is a static instance of view. If you want to keep it as is, and assuming OneViewController is already a subview on MainViewController, you should do something like this:

UIView *main = [OneViewController.view superview];
[main addSubview:twoViewController.view];

This is pretty dangerous though because you're not guaranteed to have a superview for this view. I'd just handle all of this inside MainViewController. No controller should have the power to add a subview to another controller unless it had an instance of MainViewController.

Comment: Ok so how do I tell the MainViewController to change views from an IBAction within the subview?

Comment: I tried the other option I added to my question but it still crashes

Answer (score 0):

the following code works, however it gives me 1 warning...

in my subview, OneViewController.m  (under an IBAction) ...

```
{for (UIView* next = [self.view superview]; next; next = next.superview) {
        UIResponder* nextResponder = [next nextResponder];

        if ([nextResponder isKindOfClass:[UIViewController class]]) {
            [(UIViewController*)nextResponder resetSubView];
        }`
```

in my MainViewController.m

`- (void) resetSubView {
    [self.view addSubview:twoViewController.view];
}`